# Does entity equals() and hashCode() methods contain id if I use hibernate and spring-data-jpa?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I don't want to use `id` field in `equals()` and `hashCode()` in my entity class for some business logic reason. Can I do this? Or it is bad practice?

Comment: See https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: Thank you, @M.Deinum!
I will try to read this attentively.